# What is the difference between a number and the number of connections Mysql process

Tags: mysql

How do I count the number of mysql processes running and the number of mysql connections?  What is the relationship between these two numbers?

Comment: Do you mean with code?  Through the admin screen?  Via some other means?  Also, have you attempted to count them yourself?  It's always good to show what you've tried so far, so that people know where you're at, and what kind of research you've done.

Answer (score 1):

There is no distinction between "processes" or threads when running one server. Multiple process show up due to the way the host OS "sees" the threads spun up by MySQL.

If you are sure you only started one sever, you can check the number of actual processes by running:  ps auxww|grep mysql

You can also limit the number of connections by setting: max_user_connections in your MySQL configuration.

If you have multiple MySQL instances running, you can check your threads by running: show full processlist